# Ggplot error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a graph like this:

[image]

I'm using `ggplot2` function `geom_linerange` and `geom_point` to do this. In my graph I would like to put the year variable on the y axis, the coefficient on the x axis and the confidence interval with the `geom_linerange` but I am getting this error:

`Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

If I remove the `geom_linerange`, the code works.

My code:

```
library(tidyverse)

results %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Coefficient, y = Year, color = Variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = Variable, ymin = conf.low_95, ymax = conf.high_95))
```

My `dput`:

```
structure(list(Variable = c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", 
"Model 4", "Model 5", "Model 6", "Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", 
"Model 4", "Model 5", "Model 6", "Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", 
"Model 4", "Model 5", "Model 6", "Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", 
"Model 4", "Model 5", "Model 6", "Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", 
"Model 4", "Model 5", "Model 6", "Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", 
"Model 4", "Model 5", "Model 6"), Coefficient = c(-0.337563422687641, 
-0.339870358919705, -0.174601667810286, -0.822153207427548, 0.0984725028254042, 
-0.302360726656967, -0.0144099316467553, 0.394261621304049, 0.408314375266859, 
-0.0437332910230634, 0.197918449352892, 0.211892879792213, -0.333777406931884, 
-0.211101666108092, -0.191240973701465, -0.200312029595054, 0.271332017169336, 
0.0198772428073128, -0.271118540022818, -0.296438420884506, -0.1959350798131, 
-0.604938094557287, -0.347759168324679, -0.565499762731695, 0.04352845127211, 
0.00464668179125901, 0.0618870586543521, 0.0154152406576902, 
-0.0882820982782311, -0.300512132812594, 0.354012886011799, 0.204557246817836, 
0.239302395932748, 0.419316974288796, -0.196096726024389, -0.0990227142573055
), conf.low_95 = c(-0.659882600540782, -0.652153038033736, -0.592355494245245, 
-1.15887028037482, -0.0957338272150386, -0.653747543529451, -0.360778831131537, 
-0.0547889861473285, -0.0813328193407771, -0.362272084151103, 
-0.00614433448580284, -0.0851580894901174, -0.690820142512398, 
-0.591538313876884, -0.665799398871222, -0.524239633810207, -0.00729694825470084, 
-0.312432149478429, -0.731712380556692, -0.742564839785077, -0.644569229627752, 
-1.00362824114186, -0.646168503067745, -0.872199479720429, -0.295291773790078, 
-0.366647571941097, -0.278411009308147, -0.308350900982826, -0.328643095941367, 
-0.598339525727505, -0.161377035034601, -0.674101088034365, -0.360447691535622, 
-0.0792532689562487, -0.541552105303034, -0.668221935319178), 
    conf.high_95 = c(-0.0152442448344994, -0.0275876798056746, 
    0.243152158624673, -0.485436134480278, 0.292678832865847, 
    0.0490260902155157, 0.331958967838026, 0.843312228755427, 
    0.897961569874495, 0.274805502104976, 0.401981233191587, 
    0.508943849074543, 0.0232653286486298, 0.1693349816607, 0.283317451468292, 
    0.1236155746201, 0.549960982593372, 0.352186635093054, 0.189475300511056, 
    0.149687998016065, 0.252699070001552, -0.206247947972715, 
    -0.049349833581613, -0.258800045742961, 0.382348676334298, 
    0.375940935523615, 0.402185126616851, 0.339181382298207, 
    0.152078899384905, -0.00268473989768353, 0.869402807058199, 
    1.08321558167004, 0.839052483401118, 0.917887217533841, 0.149358653254257, 
    0.470176506804567), Year = structure(c(17897, 17897, 17897, 
    17897, 17897, 17897, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18262, 
    18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
    18993, 18993, 18993, 19358, 19358, 19358, 19358, 19358, 19358, 
    19723, 19723, 19723, 19723, 19723, 19723), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two issues:

1. *I'm inferring* that `Coefficient` and the `conf.*` variables should be on the same axis, but you are plotting `x=Coefficient` and then `y*=conf*` in the linerange geom. I suspect they should both be on the y-axis.
2. Your main mapping has (after swapping for the above) `x=Year`, but your linerange geom maps `x=Variable`, a categorical variable. Since you include `color=Variable` in the first mapping, I'll infer that that should be inherited in your linerange, so I'll remove the `x=` mapping and let it inherit.

In the end, this is a reasonable start:

```r
results %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Coefficient, x = Year, color = Variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = conf.low_95, ymax = conf.high_95))
```

[image: ggplot2 fixed]

---

Side note ... it might be useful to break those lineranges apart a little. Here's a suggestion, though it is a bit fragile in that it relies on "120 days" as the dodging width, and this will be sensitive to the range of data years.

```r
results %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Coefficient, x = Year, color = Variable)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=120)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = conf.low_95, ymax = conf.high_95), position=position_dodge(width=120))
```

[image: fixed ggplot2 with the line ranges dodged laterally]

This obviously won't work if the date samples are more closely-spaced. Just a thought :-)